# Make a 2D array of Objects in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, syntax-error

I’ve written the code

```
Object[][] cells = new Object[10][10];
```

which I am hoping to later cast to

```
cells = (Cell[][]) cells;
```

but when I do I get a syntax error saying that it did not expect a semicolon where I have placed it, but instead expected what looks like white space.  If this is not the correct way to construct a 2D Object array then what is?

Comment: Your code does not make any sense. Post complete class that gives you this compilation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a 2D array of `Cell`s, you should create a 2D array of `Cell`s, not of `Object`s:

```java
Cell[][] cells = new Cell[10][10];
```